# DynamicArray of struct - adding elements without creating struct variables/objects

Tags: c++, struct, c++builder, dynamic-arrays

I have defined struct with 3 UnicodeString values, so I can create struct variable like this:

```
someStruct x = {"value1","value2","value3"};
```

But what I want to do is a DynamicArray of my struct type and I want to add elements to this array without creating them earlier, but assigning struct values the same moment I add an array element.

I tried to do it this way

```
DynamicArray<someStruct> arrayOfSomeStruct;
arrayOfSomeStruct.Length = 1; 
arrayOfSomeStruct[0] = {"value1","value2","value3"};
```

But it do not work this way. Would you help me with this?

EDIT:
I have found the solution that works but I'm not fully happy with it:

```
arrayOfSomeStruct[0].atr1 = "value";
arrayOfSomeStruct[0].atr2 = "value";
arrayOfSomeStruct[0].atr3 = "value";
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: `std::vector < someStruct > s; s.push_back( {"val1","val2","val3"} );` Still gives me a syntax error

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Why is `str` not an array or vector itself?  Why is there separate `str1`, `str2`,  etc. and not just `str[3]`?  This is why you should post a [mcve], so that we can actually see what you're trying to do instead of guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) from the standard library

Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in size.

You can try the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct SomeStruct{
    string str1;
    string str2;
    string str3;
};

int main()
{
    vector< SomeStruct > someStructVector; //Create a vector of SomeStruct

    someStructVector.push_back( {"str1 ", "str2 ", "str3"} ); //adds {"str1 ", "str2 ", "str3"} to the vector

    for( auto ss : someStructVector )//Access the elements of the vector
        cout << ss.str1 << ss.str2 << ss.str3 << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its `struct someStruct {
    UnicodeString v1;
    UnicodeString v2;
    UnicodeString v3;
};`

Comment: Try calling explicitly the  UnicodeString constructor  : someStructVector.push_back( { UnicodeString ("str1"), UnicodeString ("str2"), UnicodeString ("str3")} ):

Comment: Unfortunately It still gives me a syntax error. I think it's not matter of the var type, because it also do not work with int type

Comment: Did you forgot the #include <vector> ?

Comment: I'm afraid this also is not the issue. I have vector included

Comment: ok last try, replace vector< SomeStruct > with std::vector< SomeStruct >

Comment: Tried that before. Also did not work. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: @plxhelpme_kindofuser First is `C++ builder` compliant with C++ 11 or above?  If the code provided by the answer doesn't compile, upgrade your compiler.

Comment: @plxhelpme_kindofuser -- The code [works for Visual Studio 2015](http://rextester.com/KTNGP95779).  You need to either get a compliant compiler, or change the code to use "old" C++ syntax.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The "classic" borland-based 32bit compiler DOES NOT support C++11. The "new" clang-based 32bit compiler, and the 64bit compiler, DO support C++11.